# GET http://localhost:3001/delete 404 (Not Found)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

My index.js (Server file)

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "root",
  host: "localhost",
  password: "",
  database: "ecom_store",
});

app.post("/create", (req, res) => {
  const brand_name = req.body.brand_name;
  const brand_id = req.body.brand_id;

  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO brands (brand_name,brand_id) VALUES (?,?)",
    [brand_name, brand_id],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});

app.get("/brands", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM brands", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
  const brand_id = req.body.id;
  const brand_name = req.body.name;
  console.log(brand_id);
  console.log(brand_name);
  db.query(
    "UPDATE brands SET brand_name = ? WHERE brand_id = ?",
    [brand_name, brand_id],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("successfully updated");
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});
app.delete(`/delete`, async (req, res) => {
  const brand_id = req.body.id;
  console.log(brand_id);
  db.query(
    "DELETE FROM brands WHERE brand_id = ?",
    [brand_id],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
  );
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Yey, your server is running on port 3001");
});
```

I am on the http://localhost:3001/delete but getting this error I a using Xampp For my database
I have attached the SS of my serverPage

[![ServerPage][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2VNT.png

It works perfectly fine when I use app.get() rather than app.delete() method pls help m out with this error

Client code

```
const deleteDATA = async () => {
  const id = prompt("Enter the Id of the brand");
  axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/delete`, [id]).then((response) => {
    alert("Successfully deleted");
    console.log(response.data);
  });
};
```

Comment: tip, delete requests dont/not spec'ed to have a body, pass ids in the URL i.e `/delete/:id`

Answer (score 0):

Add the id to request body something like that for getting the id in server side.

```
axios.delete(url, { data: { id: id }, });
```

Comment: ```                                                                                                                                         
  const deleteDATA = async () => {
  const id = prompt("Enter the Id of the brand");
  axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/delete`, [id]).then((response) => {
    alert("Successfully deleted");
    console.log(response.data);
  });
};                                                                                                                                               
```     I Used axios there and did used delete not get...

Comment: I am adding it to the code pls look to it

Comment: I updated my answer to your question.